# Execute longtime threads in it's special order

Tags: java, multithreading

Many time-consuming threads (500-900ms.) are created in the application. 
They are to be executed in the order they have been created - one after another - not simultaneously. The execution should be processed in thread, that is not synchronized with main application thread.

I can't make small threads executed in an order, so I found a ThreadPoolExecutor, but think it's too heavy for my task. So I wrote my Executor class.

It works fine. You add a thread to the threadList and it start the Executor thread to execute small tasks, that can be added while execution.

Can you tell me it's drawbacks and maybe another better way to solve my problem.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class SfourExecutor extends Thread implements Runnable {

    private static List <Thread> threadList = new LinkedList<Thread>();
    private static final SfourExecutor INSTANCE = new SfourExecutor();

    public static List<Thread> getThreadList() {
        return threadList;
    }

    public static void setThreadList(List<Thread> threadList) {
        SfourExecutor.threadList = threadList;
    }

    public void addToThreadList(Thread thread) {
        getThreadList().add(thread);
        if (!this.isAlive()) {
            this.start();
        }
    }

    public static SfourExecutor getInstance() {
        return SfourExecutor.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class SfourHolder {
        private static final SfourExecutor INSTANCE = new SfourExecutor();
    }

    SfourExecutor () {
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        LinkedList <Thread> tL = (LinkedList<Thread>) getThreadList();

        while (!tL.isEmpty()) {
            Thread t = tL.poll();
            if (t!=null) {
                t.start();
                try {
                    t.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Creating a single threaded executor is a one liner using built in classes which are likely to be loaded anyway.  Can say what you are saving by creating your own thread pool? How is it better than the built implementation?

Comment: It's better to ask than not to ask. I thought that my code is faster and simplier than ThreadPoolExecutor. So why do I need to use something that was built in if I can write this smaller and easier? That's why I am trying to create my own components and classes.

Comment: It's bigger, it's harder, and it's buggy. That's why you need something that was built in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Won't an `Executor` created via [Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) meet your requirements exactly? "Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time."

Don't create new `Thread` instances when you don't need to execute jobs concurrently. Even if you are working with legacy code that has implemented some logic in a `Thread` class, you should be able to [execute](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute%28java.lang.Runnable%29) them as `Runnable` instances to the executor.

If you insist on using your own executor, you should know that your current implementation is not thread-safe. `LinkedList` is not a concurrent data structure, and since any code in the process can add new jobs at any time, you have no way to ensure that all jobs are added to the list before your executor thread is started. Thus, changes to the list are not guaranteed to be visible to all of the threads that are working with it.

Comment: Jobs can be added at any time - even if executor is executing some thread now. I don't need changes to be visible to all threads - except to the executor thread. You see - the executor thread doesn't return any result nor tasks it executes. Everything it should does - is to be ensured that the task will be done after previous and before next. My linked list is static and exist in only one thread. Isn't it enough to be sure it is thread safe? Synchronization of adding threads seemes to solve this problem.

Comment: @Malex: The list is modified by many threads (adding tasks), right? And those changes need to be visible to the executor thread (so that it can execute the tasks). For this to work reliably, you need a *memory barrier* to let the VM know that it can't optimize away the steps needed to share information between threads. The easiest way to do this would be a concurrent data structure, like `LinkedBlockingQueue`, instead of `LinkedList`. Synchronizing *all* access to the list (read *and* write) will work, but it's not as clean. There are many such pitfalls. Why not use the built-in functionality?

Comment: Sorry but I realize now that tasks are submitted by one singletone object that has all methods (that could submit) synchronized, but I understood your point and will use built in funcs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using threads instead of Runnables? Isn't it easier to have a list of Runnables and call run() on them instead than a list of thread and wait for each one to end?

Apart from this, your solution seems fine.

In both cases, I would only add some form of synchronization on addToThreadList and around the block that checks if there are tasks to execute in the run() method, since there is a possibility that the two pieces of code execute at the same time on the same linked list, which is not synchronized.

Comment: Amen! Creating threads is expensive. There's absolutely no reason to do it here. Unfortunately, there are some big problems with the way its been implemented here.

Comment: Yes I missed synchronization on addToThreadList, but why do I need another sych? How can it be that two pieces of code can be executed at the same time on the same linked list?

Comment: Just for completeness : you have one thread (the main thread probably) adding to the list, and a second thread (SfourExecutor) reading and removing from that list. These two threads can run in any order, even physically at the same time on dual core machines. LinkedList is not synchronized, so being modified by two threads at the same times can corrupt it and throw strange exceptions.

Comment: Ok. I need a synchronized list (LinkedBlockingQueue) instead of LinkedList. Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you should really consider using an Executor. I don't think you'll find it heavy:

```
int maxThreads = 1;
ExecutorService myService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxThreads);
...
myService.execute(myRunnable);
```

Always avoid rewriting something that exists already. You'll avoid writing new bugs. For instance, your implementation is not Thread safe. 2 simultaneous calls to addToThreadList expose you too an illegalthreadstateexception.

Comment: >>> 2 simultaneous calls to addToThreadList expose you too an illegalthreadstateexception. Why? Who will raise that mistake?

Comment: if two threads call SfourExecutor.getInstance().addToThreadList() at the same time, there is a risk that both thread run into "if (!this.isAlive())" while the thread is not started yet, therefore both trying to start it, resulting in an illegalthreadstate exception

Answer (score 1):

Nice code, but [Executors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)`.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads)` nice too. If your threads make long work (500-900ms) in your tasks - pool overhead not affect performance. And JIT and another JVM runtime optimization can work better with standard classes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use ThreadPoolExecutor to prevent multithreading mistakes and to make some sort of optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in that once the thread list is empty, your processing thread will stop checking for new threads added to the list. Also, `LinkedList`s aren't safe for concurrent usage, so what one thread submits might not be seen by the executor thread (or worse, it might not show up the way you submitted it). If you used a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) it would work better.

However, since you want everything to run in sequence, you don't need to create and start lots of new threads (which is pretty costly), you can just have one thread that runs lightweight `Runnable` tasks in order. `ThreadPoolExecutor` does this for you, and more, and it is also really easy to use if you take help from the [`Executors`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class (which uses `ThreadPoolExecutor`s behind the scenes):

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executorService.submit(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        doSomethingThatTakesALongTime();
    }
});
executorService.submit(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        doSomethingElseThatAlsoTakesALongTime();
    }
});
```

Concurrency isn't easy, so I'd advice you to make use of the fact that <del>Sun</del> Oracle have experts employed full-time to write and maintain these libraries for you. That means *you* get more free time you can spend at the pub, with your family, or implementing new features for your customers.

Comment: >>>if several threads call addToThreadList at the same time, the submitted threads will run in parallel. How they will run in parallel if there is only one working thread? >>> what one thread submits might not show up (or worse, might not show up the way you submitted it) to another thread. But the executor works on singleton pattern and everything is submitted to one thread is visible only to it. The submitted thread is not started in add-func, it starts only in run method of the singleton thread. In add-func I only check if the executor is working now or not (start it).

Comment: Seemes you misunderstood my code. Concurrency is to be understanded completly because it is a powerfull tool that uses almost every app now. I don't like pubs (in fact that we don't have them in Belarus), beer or smoking either, still I am single and I do my best to advance my apps as much as I can.

Comment: Ah yes, PEBKAC on my side, it started *itself* in `addToThreadList`, not the submitted thread. You still have a race condition in there, though , since several threads calling `addToThreadList` simultaneously can end up calling `this.start()`, to fix it the whole `if` statement should be in a synchronized block (or guarded otherwise).

Comment: And simultaneous call of this.start() can raise illegalthreadstateexception - so all i need is to make addToThreadList synchronized.